# I'm getting a JNI Error in my Java program, which I believe is related to dependencies

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I've seen a few posts similar to this issue, but can't seem to find a resolution that works.

My program is using UCanAccess dependencies, and everything runs great using inteliJ. Once I try to run the JAR file, I get the following:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature
igest for Manifest main attributes
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown So
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Sourc
at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I know this has to do with dependencies because I have another program without dependencies that I've configured the exact same way, and this works fine.

This is a Windows 7 Machine. The JDK was already downgraded to Windows 7, which was an issue I faced with a previous project on this machine.

Here is what I can show:

[image]

[image]

My Manifest File simply states:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Main
```

Any ideas?